# Open Local PDF in Android in WebView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, pdf

Code

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url);
```

This works pretty well when im trying to open an online pdf

I want the user to choose a pdf in his phone and i want to open that pdf in webview.
Is there a way to achieve this in android? I have the PDF Location. Just want to open in

Comment: now, why load in WebView???

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You can't do that.
Read some websites first before creating apps.